# Solving convex combination of Arithmetic and Geometric on random variables

Tags: probability, nonlinear

This is my term project for non-linear stochastic optimization and the main problem is solving $f(x_{1},...x_{n})$, i.e., I need to maximize $f(x_{1},...x_{n})$ and find $X=(x_{1},...x_{n})$

where $0\leq z \leq 1$ is known, $0\leq x_{i}\leq 1$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{i=n}x_{i} =1$.
$Y_{1},...Y_{n}$ are independent positive (>0) random variables with probability distribution $P_{Y_{i}}$ and mean $\mu_{i}$ (expected vlaue :$\mu_{i}$ =$E[Y_{i}]=\sum P_{Y_{i}}Y_{i} $).
Also, the probability distribtion of the convex combination of $Y_{i}s$ ,$\sum_{i=1}^{i=n}x_{i}*Y_{i}$, is  $P_{Y1,...,Yn}$. Due to indepency of random variables $P_{Y1,...,Yn}=P_{Y_{1}}*P_{Y_{2}}*...P_{Y_{n}}$.

The function f is a convex combination of Arithmetic-Geometric (A-G) means, $z$ handles the convex combination of A-G means. 
$\sum_{i=1}^{i=n}(x_{i}\mu_{i})=\sum_{i=1}^{i=n}(x_{i}E(Y_{i}))$ is the arithmetic mean of random variables 
and the second term is geometric mean of the random variables that I converted to $exp(.)$ term to make it easier to deal with. In original form, it should be $\Pi(\sum_{i=1}^{i=n}(x_{i}Y_{i}))^{P_{Y_{1},...,Y_{n}}}$
= $exp(P_{Y_{1},...,Y_{n}}\ln(\sum_{i=1}^{i=n}(x_{i}Y_{i})))$. in other words, its $E[\ln(\sum_{i=1}^{i=n}(x_{i}Y_{i}))]$.

In this problem everything is known expect $X=(x_{1},...,x_{n})$, and
I need a closed form solution based on $X$ but due to the nonlinearity of the function $f$, I believe some estimations such as Taylor is needed to get rid of $ln(.)$ and/or $exp(.)$ terms.

As an simple example, let assume $n=2$, $P_{Y_{1}}(Y_{1}=2)=1$, and $P_{Y_{2}}(Y_{2}=1)=P_{Y_{2}}(Y_{2}=3)=0.5$ and $E[Y_{1}]=1, E[Y_{2}]=2 $ and $z=0.5$, then $f(x_{1},x_{2})$ is 
$f(x_{1},x_{2}) =0.5(2x_{1}+2x_{2})+0.5*\exp(0.5\ln(2x_{1}+x_{2})+0.5\ln(2x_{1}+3x_{2}))$. now, the question is finding $X=(x_{1},x_{2})$ where $ 0  \leq x_{1},x_{2}\leq 1$ and $x_{1}+x_{2}=1$.

Comment: You should have edited your other post http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/254008/how-to-solve-convex-combination-of-positive-random-variables and addressed all those comments. Your $f(x_{1},...x_{n})$ as currently written doesn't make any sense. If you're trying to maximize something, it must evaluate to a scalar given values of the variables, $x_1, ..., x_n$ you're optimizing. There are random variables on the right-hand-side - those don't evaluate to a scalar. A lot of other stuff doesn't make much sense either. You seem to be mixing up several concepts having to do with probability.

Comment: It seems that you want to maximize some function of a convex combination of random variables. I.e., find the optimal convex combination. But what that function is supposed to be is hardly obvious to me. You need to figure out what the 2nd (additive) term of the right-hand side is supposed to be.  If n = 2, can you write it out explicitly?

Comment: You can check the example I added to the end of the problem description.

Answer (score 1):

Your example is trivially solved with optimal $x_1 = 1, x_2 = 0$, regardless of the value of $z$ (irrelevance of the value of $z$ in this example is because means of the random variables are equal). In this particular example, $f$ is monotonically increasing from its minimum at $x1 = 0$ to its maximum at $x_1 = 1$.

More generally, a problem of the form you provided will be a linearly constrained nonlinear optimization problem which can be solved using a numerical nonlinear optimizer which can accept linear constraints.

If there's a general closed form solution, I'll leave that for someone else to figure out. But perhaps there is a closed form for special cases.  It's easy to calculate the gradient of $f$, and therefore easy to write out the Karush-Kuhn-Tucker conditions https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions which due to the linear constraints, are necessary for a maximum, but are sufficient for a maximum only if $f$ is concave on the constraint region. However, I don't think they will admit a closed-form solution, except in cases, such as your example, in which the optimum is at a vertex. Perhaps someone can characterize the conditions on the probability distributions for which the solution will be at a vertex.

**Edit**: Why do you "need" a closed form solution? What will the closed form solution be used for? If the closed form solution is an approximation, does it matter how accurate the approximation is? I presume it does, in which case the approximation could come at an inaccuracy cost which is unacceptable. Is a solution obtained by numerical nonlinear optimization acceptable? If not, why not?